# Subtract the count -1 when particular slot is selected in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to book admission slot in php. 
table slot contains fields date,allowed,remaining
Each day has 100 slots  Once he registers the remaining field, 1 must subtracted and updated.That is if total students for one date in remaining field(initially) is 100 then it should become 99, 98 etc (same field). The remaining field when updated doesnt get updated.
Here is the code

```
<form action="" method="post">

<label>Mobile No</label>
<input type="text" name="mobile"/><br/>
<label>Applicant Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
<label>Date of Interview Choosen</label>
<input type="text"  name="date" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['date'])) { echo $_GET['date']; } ?>" readonly /><br/>
<label>Report Time Choosen</label>
<input type="text" name="time" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['time'])) { echo $_GET['time']; } ?>" readonly /><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="confirm">
</form>
<?php
include_once "db.php";
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$name=$_POST["name"];
$date=$_POST["date"];
$time=$_POST["time"];

$res = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM slot WHERE date='$date'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

$date=$row['date'];

$remaining= $row['remaining'];
$remaining = $remaining - 1;    
mysql_query("UPDATE slot SET remaining = $remaining WHERE date=$date"); 
 $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO reg (name, mobile, date, time) 
                VALUES('$name', '$mobile', '$date', '$time')") or die(mysql_error());

    if($query)
    {   $id=mysql_insert_id();
        $_SESSION['id']=$id;
        header("Location:reg1.php");

    }}
?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements.  `WHERE date=$date` isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: Why are you using the long-dead `mysql_` library? It shouldn't be used for any new code. Development and bug-fixes stopped many years ago and it is removed entirely in PHP7. It also leaves you vulnerable to SQL injections (due to lack of support for parameterisation). Switch to mysqli or PDO instead asap and start using parameterised queries.  This will reduce the risk of injection attacks and also (as Tim mentioned above) remove the potential for errors like this where your variables aren't behaving the way you expect when inlcuded in your query.